# Microsoft.Owin version conflict

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I want to update 'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend' nuget package to the latest package, but when I try to do it I get an error

> Updating 'Microsoft.Owin 3.0.0' to 'Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1' failed.
>   Unable to find a version of 'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend' that
>   is compatible with 'Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1'.

but Microsoft.Owin package already has 3.0.1 version.

[image: http://magicscreenshot.blob.core.windows.net/screenshots/ic8fQFP0OUg.jpg]

Why it happened and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend at the time of writing is 1.0.470.

Looking at the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend 1.0.470 NuGet package it has a dependency on Microsoft.Owin version 3.0.0 and the [dependency is defined so it only works with that version](https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning). From the .nuspec file in the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend NuGet package:

```
<dependency id="Microsoft.Owin" version="[3.0.0]" />
```

If you need WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend 1.0.470 you would need to install Microsoft.Owin version 3.0.0 and not 3.0.1 since the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend 1.0.470 NuGet package is not compatible with 3.0.1.